# WooCommerce - Randomize the product image sizes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there anyway to randomize the sizes of product images? So they are different size squares?

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to build an image slider and need different size squares to make a nice grid that scrolls. Anyone got a trick to modify the output of the product images?